# How can I solve Exercise 8.15a) in Introduction to PDE's (Tveito, Winther)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am struggling with a) on the following exercise, taken from *Introduction to PDE's* (Tveito, Winther):

[image]

On a): I tried computing $((1+x)X_1'(x))' = X_1'(x) + (1+x)X_1''(x)$ by hand and seeing if it equals $\beta^2 X_1(x)$, but I got

$((1+x)X_1'(x))' = \frac{(1 - 4 \beta^2) \cos(\beta \log(1 + x)) + 4 \beta \sin(\beta \log(1 + x))}{4 (1 + x)^{3/2}} $.

I feel like this should be trivial and that I'm doing something silly, but I can't see what. Hints?

Comment: I did the computation as well and got the same answer as you

Comment: The substitution $t = 2\beta\sqrt{1+x}$ yields the modified Bessel's equation $t^2 \frac{d^2X}{dt^2} + t \frac{dX}{dt} - t^2 X = 0$. So the fundamental solutions are modified Bessel functions of order zero, $I_0, K_0$. I think there is a mistake somewhere in the exercise.

Comment: Try the ODE $-((1+x)^2X')' = (\beta^2 + \frac{1}{4}) X$ with the solutions $X_1, X_2$ given in the exercise. It seems like the authors want you to consider a special case of (8.30) in (a).

Comment: @Christoph Those definitely work, thanks. I'll look at the problem some more.